# Ember normalize response

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm extending the `JSONSerializer` in order to fit my server response which looks like this:

```js
{
  "result": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "...",
        "title": "...",
        ...
      },
      ...
    ],
      "total": number,
      "...": "..."
  }   
}
```

therefore I have overridden `normalizeResponse()` method:

```js
normalizeResponse: function(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
        payload = payload.result.items;

        return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType)
    },
```

after this my model data fields are all `undefined`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your JSON format could be invalid. Which version of ember are you using?

Comment: @nem Ember 2.2.1. Anyway I have fixed this so I'll post an answer when I get back to my workstation.

Comment: @AndreiStalbe could you please post your answer here !!